# Multiple canvas elements to data url?

Tags: html, canvas

I am about to develop a HTML5 application that uses canvas. I will be needing multiple layers for the project as the app requires drawing multiple text areas on top of an image. These text areas will need to be resizable depending on the length of the string.

Now having read some posts on SO I realize there are two methods for multiple layers:

1. Simply creating multiple canvas elements and stack them on top of each other with z-index
2. Create layers using a ready made framework that uses just one canvas element

Option 1 seems the easier, however (and this is my question), can I save the result of method 1 to a data URL or flat image of some kind?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you want the user to write to the text areas or do you just want to output some text there? If you want the latter one, you simply can use the `device.fillText("sometext",xposition,yposition)`. note that x and y are relative to the origo of the coordinate system of your device.

Comment: The user will be writing into a normal html input box

Comment: You can “flatten” multiple canvas images into one by just copying the content of the other canvas elements over to the first one in any order you like – and then you can get the data URI for the one canvas that is left.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the content of images, canvas and video onto another canvas, so you could do this:

```
/// draw the background image
ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);

/// draw and scale text to fit main canvas
ctx.drawImage(txtCanvas1, x, y, newWidth, newHeight);

/// draw and scale text to fit main canvas
ctx.drawImage(txtCanvas2, x, y, newWidth, newHeight);
```

Then you simply extract everything from this canvas:

```
var flattenedImage = canvas.toDataURL();
```

This **[ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Tb3Ec/)** shows the principle described here. Just enter a long text and you can see it gets sandwiched with the background image as you type. The content can be extracted as a single image data-uri.